# sqlite and php when open database

Tags: php, sqlite

now, i'm trying to write program using php and sqlite, but i have problem. browser shows error to me, can u help me to correct my program? this is the sourcecode

```
<?php
$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$pass_id = $_POST["pass_id"];

$database = sqlite_open("database_support/user_acces...");
$result = sqlite_query($database, "select * from user_table where user_id like     '$user_id' and pass_id like '$pass_id'");

if($result){
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
$_SESSION["pass_id"] = $pass_id;
$_SESSION["time_id"] = time() + 10;
echo ($_SESSION["time_id"]);
}
else{
header("location:index.php");   
}   
?>
```

result from chrome browser :

```
Warning: sqlite_open() [function.sqlite-open]: unable to open database: C:\xampp\htdocs\aptana\gsy\document_supp… in C:\xampp\htdocs\aptana\gsy\document_supp… on line 5

Warning: sqlite_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\aptana\gsy\document_supp… on line 6

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\aptana\gsy\document_supp… in C:\xampp\htdocs\aptana\gsy\document_supp… on line 15
```

can anybody help me,? thanks 4 ur time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sqllite_open should be like below code. in your code it seems something lacking.
If you want to use session in any file then you have to start session before use it
So your code must be like this sample code.

```
<?php 
session_start();

$dbhandle = sqlite_open('db/test.db', 0666, $error);

if (!$dbhandle) die ($error);

$query = "SELECT Name, Sex FROM Friends";
$result = sqlite_query($dbhandle, $query);
if (!$result) die("Cannot execute query.");
?>
```

Comment: well, its right for now, but i still have problem. The browser said <p> Warning: SQLiteDatabase::query() [sqlitedatabase.query]: no such table: user_table in C:\xampp\htdocs\aptana\gsy\document_support\checkpoint.php on line 16 no such table: user_table </p>

i make database using sqlite manager in mozilla adds on. my question now " can we make database using sqlite manager and connect it with php to do some query such as "select *from user_table" ?

Comment: i think table is not exist in your DB

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the file is valid `sqlite` file. Also need to do `session_start` since you are trying to access `$_SESSION` inside this file. Also `location` change should not be preceded by anyother html content.